Sum of positive and negative hours at work
I have a spreadsheet in Excel 365 where I'm recording worked hours and not worked hours. I would like to sum them in the column to see the balance of the hours the worker is due or owes. So I have a set of hours that were used in both positive and negative ways. So from cell K8 to O8 I have recorded time 2:50,2:30,-1:45,1:30,-2.45 and I would like to SUM them to see if the balance is negative or positive and how much time is owed or earned. I was trying to use a formula:
=IF(SUM(C8:Y8>=0,TEXT(SUM(C8:Y8),"Hh:mm"),Text(ABS(SUM(C8:Y8),"-hh:mm"))

But instead of the result Excel 365 doing that:

Can you please help me to sort this out or point me in the right direction? the cells are formatted as a text and when I'm formatting them as a time it won't allow me to record the negative time.

can you show how the time looks?  Date/Time in Excel cannot be negative.  So my guess is that they text that looks like numbers.

Also how is that formula working for you, you should have got an error message, --> You;ve entered too many arguments for this function?

Thank you for the response. So the cells are formatted as "general" As you have pointed you cannot record the negative time. they are stored in the format 00:00 or -00:00. Yes I'm getting an error from the formula but 365 is not showing me what is the problem.

If they are formatted as General and they look like -1:45 then they are TEXT and SUM will not add them.  But the issue with your formula is that you are missing a ): =IF(SUM(C8:Y8)>=0,TEXT(SUM(C8:Y8),"Hh:mm"),Text(ABS(SUM(C8:Y8)),"-hh:mm"))  But again I doubt this will give you the answer you are expecting.

You are using Excel for web and that is the reason why those dotted dashes appear, if you were using from desktop then you should have got the error message.

you can try something like this: =LET(rng,C8:Y8,tm,REDUCE(0,rng,LAMBDA(z,y,z+IF(LEFT(y)="-",-MID(y,2,LEN(y)),--y))),TEXT(ABS(tm),IF(tm<0,"-","")&"hh:mm"))

or: =LET(rng,C8:Y8,sm,SUM(IF(LEFT(rng)="-",-MID(rng,2,10),--rng)),TEXT(ABS(sm),IF(sm<0,"-","")&"hh:mm"))

Thank you @ScottCraner, the first formula returning #VALUE! "Formula is using the wrong data type" and the second is just sitting in the cell with no results returned.

Then we need a lot more information. like how the data in those cells are created. and examples and expected output.
